# Execution skipping getline()

Tags: c++

After ending first while with ctrl+d the program skips "cin >> contBuscado"
and goes to the for.
I dont know why this is happening, i've used .ignore and .clear but nothing happens.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<vector>
 using namespace std;

struct Contacto{
string nombre;
int numero;
}contacto;

int main() {

vector<Contacto> listaContactos;

while(cout<<"Nombre:" && getline(cin,contacto.nombre)){
    cout<<"Telefono:";
    cin>>contacto.numero;
    cin.ignore();
    listaContactos.push_back(contacto);
}
cin.clear();

cout << "\nIntroduce el nombre del contacto a buscar: ";
string contBuscado="";
cin >> contBuscado;
cin.ignore();

for(Contacto const& con:listaContactos){
    if(con.nombre==contBuscado){
        cout<<"El telefono de "<<contBuscado<<" es "<<con.numero<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
cout<<"\nEl contacto introducido no se encuentra en la lista\n";

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Read carefully what `std::istream::ignore()` does, with its default parameters, according to its documentation. Better yet, get rid of `>>` and `ignore()` altogether, and use `std::getline` exclusively. That's what `std::getline()` is for: read a line of input ending with a newline. That's not what `>>` is for. Trying to use a concoction of `>>`, `ignore`(), and `clear`(), to accomplish what `std::getline()` does naturally, is a recipe for a migraine headache. Just use `std::getline()`. Much simpler. Fewer surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ending input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, you have ended standard input for your program. At this point you cannot supply any more input.

You will need to add a way for the user to exit the `while` loop, such as by entering a blank line.

Also, you will find it much easier to use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in all cases instead of `cin >>`. The use of `cin >>` is not recommended for interactive input, because its behaviour can be confusing.

Comment: Ok so basically this was it. Ctrl + D ends all input in mac/XCode, while in Windows it ends just the current input and goes to the next (cin, getline or whatever). Thank you @greg-hewgill.